# Strange Greater Than Logic with Numbers in Character Vector

Tags: r, logic, character

I was working on a script today, and noticed some very unexpected outputs. Upon inspection, I found that one variable in my dataset, which should always be numeric, has one character value (essentially one cell with a typed "N/A" rather than a value properly read in as NA). This is not really a problem, as I can manually re-code this value as NA. What I am curious about is why I did not receive an error while indexing on this vector, and how to interpret the output. An example is provided below:

```
c("56.2", "84.7", "63", "9", "109.5", "16", "N/A", "50") >= 50
```

Results in the output:

```
TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

The logic behind which entries are marked as TRUE or FALSE is not immediately obvious to me. Could anyone provide an explanation?

Comment: Study `help("Comparison")`. It answers your question.

Comment: supporting the answers you've received, to see it from R's perspective, execute `sort(c("56.2", "84.7", "63", "9", "109.5", "16", "N/A", "50", 50))`

Answer (score 2):

Because a comparison on characters is done on alphabetical order and numbers come before letters, "100.9" starts with a 1 so comes first than the 5 in "50" and therefor "smaller" / earlier in order.

```
"ab" > "b"
# a comes before b
# [1] FALSE

"12" > "2"
# 1 comes before 2 as character
# [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Additional note to the explanation by Merjin van Tilborg:

```
x <- c("56.2", "84.7", "63", "9", "109.5", "16", "N/A", "50") 
x >= 50

# gives
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

# Now check which indexes fulfill this comparison (the why is explained by Merjin van Tilborg)
which(x >= 50)
[1] 1 2 3 4 7 8

# if you do like this:
as.numeric(x) >=50

# you get:
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE    NA  TRUE
Warning message:
  NAs introduced by coercion
```